# How to get Installshield to enter repair mode from Setup.exe?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2015

Our installer has a setup.exe file which internally contains the Msi.

Once installed, the option to repair is available from the programs and features right click context menu.

However when repair is selected, a dialog is shown which gives the option to browse for the msi.

Since the msi is nested in setup.exe, and since the installer was not able to find any appropriate msi in appdata, this has rendered the repair functionality all but useless.

Is it possible to change the installer, so that it can repair from setup.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three main options, depending on which scenarios you want to support:

- Just double-click the setup.exe, and if the msi is already installed it will run in maintenance mode. You can select to repair it from there. This is good for a one-time scenario.
- Run setup.exe with the /a argument, which creates an administrative installation point for the install. This can just be a folder on your desktop, or anywhere you like. This is also good for a one-time scenario, and should be compatible with launching repair from Programs and Features.
- Configure your installation to cache the .msi package by using the setting in the Releases view. This should enable all maintenance scenarios for everyone, at the ongoing cost of some hard drive space.

Comment: I removed the repair option in the end, it was a setting found in InstallShield.